# Why PropertyInfo.GetValue() need the instance to retrieve the value?

Tags: c#, reflection

The [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z852kf5.aspx) class has the [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx) method which takes two parameters, the first one is the instance of the property.
Well it's just doesn't make sense to me, why the ProperyInfo doesn't hold the value? 
I get the PropertyInfo from the instance and then I need the Instance again to retrieve the value?!
That's weird.

Can someone please explain me why C# built that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `PropertyInfo` is "metadata"; it is associated with a property defined on a *type*, not an instance.

Comment: @gdoron: An object of the type in question essentially holds the metadata + values. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `PropertyInfo` class is designed on a per-type basis. The `PropertyInfo` resembles the property on the class, and not on the instance. That's why you need the instance to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

the propertyinfo generates from the instance only the construction plan and not the values itself